# How do two waves after approaching and neutralising each other give birth to two waves the very next moment?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

[image]
My question is after the third event(in the picture) how do the waves originate again? 
An obvious answer might be that two waves simply propagate and just add up when they interfere with each other. But if we take a closer look, in the third position, all the velocities are perfectly cancelled out. Then why should another set of waves originate?
Wouldn't it be mysterious to an observer who starts observing from the third position?

Can anyone give me a mechanical interpretation? Where am I making the mistake?

Comment: It is not the velocities that have cancelled, it is the positions.  Each atom in the rope still has a velocity.

Comment: Related.  [Why does destructive interference not stop a wave?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386043/104696)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the third position the different parts of the string still have vertical velocities that aren't shown.

The wave equation is second order in time, so you need to specify the vertical velocities of each part. Not just the position.